# How to resolve Phonegap error while Building the app

Tags: iphone, xcode

all

I made a sample application with the help of Phonegap, while building the app it gives me two error .

Error1:

error: 'NSEC_PER_MSEC' undeclared (first use in this function)

Error2:

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

by the way I am using Xcode 3.2.5 (4.2),

can any buddy know this answer then plz tell me..

it is for the xcode 4.3 only?? b/c on this link http://www.phonegap.com/start they run their application through xocde 4.3

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem - seems there is a typo in their production code. You need to change 'NSEC_PER_MSEC' to 'NSEC_PER_SEC' and it should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just comment that line.. of code because it has no actual use to test I had the same error and was resolved by commenting :P.. and it runs on ios 4.2 smoothly...

Comment: I successfully solve that problem by inserting 1000000ull to the NSEC_PER_MSEC ..

thnx

Comment: thnx for the reply Hardik I successfully solve that problem by inserting 1000000ull to the NSEC_PER_MSEC ..

Comment: yup.. but what i wanted to say is that wont make ny sence if u put that code or not..