# XCode 3 - core compile errors with clean installation and iPhone 4 SDK

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

This is a copy of [another question from AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43517/xcode-3-core-compile-errors-with-clean-installation-and-iphone-4-sdk), since I'm being adviced to put this question here instead.

---

This has been asked once elsewhere but nobody could give the guy an answer... and I Google seem to only know that single occurrence of the problem!

So I'm the second guy in history to experience this and my problem is:

- I'm running **XCode 3.2.3** on **Snow Leopard 10.6.4** (I think, it's the minimal required OS version for this XCode version) with **iOS SDK 4.0.2**
- I create a new empty Cordoba (PhoneGap) project
- I set up my Base SDK in Project Settings to **iPhone Simulator 4.0** per instructions on PhoneGap's website
- I don't change any other setting at all
- when I hit "Build and Run" button, XCode starts compilation and finished with 3 errors and 10 warnings

Now, I don't mind those warning, but I cannot successfully compile because of those 3 errors now. No idea how to fix this, I'm totally new to PhoneGap or Mac OS for that matter.

The errors I get are:

```
/Users/[name]/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVLocation.m:123:32 /Users/[name]/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVLocation.m:123:32: error: use of undeclared identifier 'kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized'
/Users/[name]/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCapture.m:783:70 /Users/[name]/Documents/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVCapture.m:783:70: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSEC_PER_MSEC'
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I would appreciate any advice from you guys, as I'm completely at a dead-end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLAuthorizationStatus`, and thus `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` are only available in 4.2 and later.

Check this for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized

As to your other error, google pulls up this: [How to resolve Phonegap error while Building the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592861/how-to-resolve-phonegap-error-while-building-the-app)

Comment: does that mean that I need an older PhoneGap version of can I somehow workaround this by adding that piece of code into a JS file somewhere?

Comment: I have no idea about PhoneGap, sorry. Never used it. Finding another page, seems to be a problem with versions of xCode prior to 3.2.6.